# First example of "super-wealthy steal younger bodies for immortality" plot?

Tags: science-fiction, first-appearance

What is the earliest film or show whose plot incorporated some process by which super-wealthy/powerful people achieve immortality by continually transferring their mind (and then wealth) into the bodies of (non-consenting) healthy young adults?

*[Self/less](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2140379/?ref_=nv_sr_1)* appears to be a recent example.  *[Freejack](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104299/?ref_=nv_sr_1)* predates it by a generation.  But I suspect it has been used earlier.

Comment: There's the 1979 sci-fi movie *Parts: The Clonus Horror*  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parts%3A_The_Clonus_Horror which features the wealthy & powerful growing clones and then killing them to harvest spare organs. Although that's actually just the reverse of what you asked.

Comment: This is the [Body Surf Trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BodySurf)

Comment: 1979 beats the tales from the crypt that I'm remembering. There was a tales where a wealthy man 'bought' the body of a younger man (they traded brains or something).

Comment: There's 1970's ["The Man who Wanted to Live Forever" aka "The Only Way Out is Dead" aka "The Heart Farm"](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0066054/)

Comment: Wikapedia does have a list of Lit, Films, and TV series about "mind uploading", but I don't see anything older than what has already been suggested here, with your "specific" conditions. But in case you are interested: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_uploading_in_fiction

Answer (score 2):

[Seconds (1966)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seconds_(1966_film)) is an example of this, it's pretty much ripped off in Self/less.

Answer (score 2):

Twilight Zone Season 3 episode 31 "The Trade-Ins," air date April 20 1962.
[IMDB description](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0734679/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2):

> An elderly couple shop for younger replacement bodies, then resort to
>   desperate measures to cover the cost.

While the couple in the episode is not rich, they are requesting a service you would have to be rich to take advantage of.